# Change camelCase to CONSTANT_CASE for the block of code in vim

Tags: vim, vscodevim

I am using vim's [abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) plugin to change camelCase variables to CONSTANT_CASE (UPPER_CASE in abolish lang) using `cru`

My Question:

I have an enum with 100 such variables, so naturally I want to know is there a way to use `cru` command over the block of code.

e.g.

```
MacAddr0High        = 0x000,  // address0 high Register

MacAddr0Low         = 0x004,  // address0 low Register

MacAddr1High        = 0x008,  // address1 high Register

MacAddr1Low         = 0x00C,  // address1 low Register

MacAddr2High        = 0x010,  // address2 high Register

.

.
```

*I would like to change the variable name only and not the description*

Currently all I can think of is to use `cru` and then repeat the command using `.` which is not the best approach.

I looked at some of the similar questions, which suggested going in the visual mode and using `~` `u` / `U`

But I can not use `cru` in visual mode. Maybe because its a plugin.

I can use VsCodeVim too, if it has a way of doing it.

Comment: so cru works? Would the global command help? `:g/MacAddr/norm cru`

Comment: cru works for just the variable under the cursor. I will try global command and let you know

Comment: `:g/MacAddr/norm cru` it worked in the reserve manner converted MAC_ADDR0_HIGH to MacAddr0High

Comment: Sorry I did not understand what you meant with your last comment, is there still a problem?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for not being clear.
I have converted a variable to MAC_ADDR0_HIGH using `cru`
after that when I used `:g/MacAddr/norm cru` it converted CONSTANT_CASE to camelCase

Comment: can't reproduce that `cru` on `MAC_ADDR0_HIGH` for example does nothing. Have you overwritten your mapping?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. But I have not changed anything / have to overwritten any mapping...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comment, you could use the plugin and a global command and solve it with:

```
:g/MacAddr/norm cru
```

Without the plugin a search and replace could  help:

```
:%s/\v(\L\l+)(\L\l+)(\d+)(\L\l+)/\U\1_\U\2_\3_\U\4/g
```

A recurisve macro would be a third thing to look for.

Comment: It would be more generic to extract the thing to transform then use `substitute(...., 'g')` through `:s\=` -- which is the core of my `ConvertNames` command.

Comment: @Doktor Oswaldo - can you please explain `:%s/\v(\L\l+)(\L\l+)(\d+)(\L\l+)/\U\1_\U\2_\3_\U\4/g`

Comment: @LucHermitte Absolutly! But wanted to point out the three most common ways to solve questions like this: 1. Repeat the command on every line with `g`. 2, Use a `substitute` 3. Repeat the command don every found pattern with a recursive macro. Of course there are more advanced generic solutions. But I often find myself needing a quick and diry one time solution for this kind of problems.

Comment: @HarshaD It is a search and replace which works by splitting the term up in 3 groups of words (starting with an letter `\L` followed by some lowercase letters `\l`) and a group of numbers (`\d`). Then replace the found groups with the uppercase version of the group (`\U` transforms the capturing group to uppercase) and concat them with a underscore.

Comment: @Doktor OSwaldo : Thanks for the explanation. This does work but it replaces the string match in comments too. But I can live with that...

Comment: You could improve that by add a test for that before in the regex. But I guess you are not yet familiar with regexes? If not have a look on it. Regexes are extremely useful and powerful and usable in every programming language and most editors!

Answer (score 1):

(Not directly your question, yet with [lh-style](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-style) you could use `:%ConvertNames/^\k\+/SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE`)

Otherwise, may be

```
:g/^MacA/normal cru
```

should work as expected as what you wish to change is at the beginning of the line. It would be a little bit more complex otherwise.

Comment: `:g/^MacA/normal cru` says pattern not found: ^MacA....
would take a look at lh-style! Thanks

Comment: If `^MacA` is not found, it means your lines are not starting with `MacA`. It may be a little more complex then as you'll need to move the cursor to the word you wish to change.